# what is the size of High Density WVGA854 launcher icon?

Tags: android, android-widget

i have created the launcher icon(48x48 px) for 320x480 screen resolution and it's working fine. but while using same icon in WVGA854(480x854 px) it's displaying small compare to other default launcher icon.

i want to know, what is the size of High Density WVGA854 launcher icon?

Regards,
Jeyavel N

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do believe the ideal size for WVGA-icons are 72*72

Cheers,